# How do you return a name from an array of hashes Ruby TDD

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, tdd

First I am new to programing and here is the issue

This is the spec

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative '../pet_shop'

class TestPetShop < Minitest::Test
  def setup
    @customers = [{
      name: "Craig",
      pets: [],
      cash: 1000
    }, {
      name: "Zsolt",
      pets: [],
      cash: 50
    }]

    @new_pet = {
      name: "Bors the Younger",
      pet_type: :cat,
      breed: "Cornish Rex",
      price: 100
    }

    @pet_shop = {
      pets: [{
        name: "Sir Percy",
        pet_type: :cat,
        breed: "British Shorthair",
        price: 500
      }, {
        name: "King Bagdemagus",
        pet_type: :cat,
        breed: "British Shorthair",
        price: 500
      }, {
        name: "Sir Lancelot",
        pet_type: :dog,
        breed: "Pomsky",
        price: 1000,
      }, {
        name: "Arthur",
        pet_type: :dog,
        breed: "Husky",
        price: 900,
      }, {
        name: "Tristan",
        pet_type: :dog,
        breed: "Basset Hound",
        price: 800,
      }, {
        name: "Merlin",
        pet_type: :cat,
        breed: "Egyptian Mau",
        price: 1500,
      }],
      admin: {
        total_cash: 1000,
        pets_sold: 0,
      },
      name: "Camelot of Pets"
    }
  end

  def test_find_pet_by_name__returns_pet
    pet = find_pet_by_name(@pet_shop, "Arthur")
    assert_equal("Arthur", pet[:name])
  end
end
```

And here is my answer

```
  def find_pet_by_name(shop)
    pets = []

    for pet in shop[:pets]
      if pet[:name] == name
       return pet
      end
    end

    return pets 
  end
```

Keep getting wrong number of arguments error please remember i clearly don't know what i am doing as i am new programing.

Comment: Please submit the actual error message.

Comment: You've defined your method `find_pet_by_name` with one parameter yet you've called the method with two arguments in your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your `find_pet_by_name(shop)` method here:

```
pet = find_pet_by_name(@pet_shop, "Arthur")
```

As a commenter mentions, you're passing 2 arguments when calling the method: `@pet_shop` and `"Arthur"`. But your method definition only allows for passing in 1 argument: `shop`. So your method call should really be:

```
pet = find_pet_by_name(@pet_shop)
```

There's no need to pass in "Arthur", since that information isn't required (or allowed in) by the method. Hence the 'wrong number of arguments' error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your help just got it to pass could not get my head around the two arguments passing through the function only had one parameter listed i had to pass 2 to get it working. Thank you again